# Add node to XML

Tags: c#, xml, json.net

I have some JSON that I need to add a property to and convert to XML string.

I have managed to get the conversion to XML working .....

```
answersJsonStr = '{"question1":"answer 1","question2":"answer b"}';

XNode node = 
    Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(answersJsonStr, "answersXml");
var answersXml = node.ToString();
```

This produces XML correctly....

```
<answersXml>
  <question1>answer 1</question1>
  <question2>answer b</question2>
</answersXml>
```

But I am completely lost when it comes to adding in a property. I.e.  I want to add to get this...

```
<answersXml>
  <question1>answer 1</question1>
  <question2>answer b</question2>
  <cardId>12334556789</cardId>
</answersXml>
```

I have reading many similar question and they seem to suggest I should be using XElement as its simpler. But I cant figure out how to convert XNode to XElement. Or maybe I could Deserialise directly to XElement. But I cant figure this out either. What is the best 'XML type' to use?

Also, I have been reading htis...
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xnode_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
But I cant figure out much from it. Is there any better documentation you would recommend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeXNode_2.htm) returns `XDocument`, so just use appropriate node type:

```
XDocument xdoc = JsonConvert.DeserializeXNode(answersJsonStr, "answersXml");
```

And then add element to root:

```
xdoc.Root.Add(new XElement("cardId", 123456789));
```